# How to tell ModemManager to ignore some or all of tttyUSB*?

Tags: modem-manager

I want to tell `ModemManager` to leave my Tungsten E (Palm Pilot) alone. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

My logs tell me:

```
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0830, idProduct=0060
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: Product: Palm Handheld
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Palm, Inc.
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: PalmSN12345678
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: visor 1-1.1:1.0: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter detected
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat kernel: usb 1-1.1: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat mtp-probe[5886]: checking bus 1, device 29: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1"
Jul 30 22:00:41 bat mtp-probe[5886]: bus: 1, device: 29 was not an MTP device
Jul 30 22:00:43 bat snapd[1623]: hotplug.go:193: hotplug device add event ignored, enable experimental.hotplug
Jul 30 22:00:43 bat snapd[1623]: hotplug.go:193: hotplug device add event ignored, enable experimental.hotplug
Jul 30 22:00:45 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
Jul 30 22:00:45 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Jul 30 22:01:27 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): close blocked by driver for more than 7 seconds!
Jul 30 22:01:33 bat ModemManager[1303]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Generic' and '2' ports
Jul 30 22:01:33 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB1): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB1', unhandled seria
Jul 30 22:01:33 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB0', unhandled seria
Jul 30 22:01:33 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
Jul 30 22:02:04 bat ModemManager[1303]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): close blocked by driver for more than 7 seconds!
```

I want to prevent `ModemManager` from trying anything with `/dev/ttyUSB[01]` or even `/dev/ttyUSB*`.

Comment: and dont want to disable the service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a udev rule file, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-palm.rules`:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0830", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0060", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

Reload the udev rules:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

Plug in your Palm device.

Comment: What about being able to ignore some ports of the device, but keep using the others? e.g. ignore /dev/ttyUSB0, but use all others?

Comment: Ok, I found the discussion here: https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/14197#issuecomment-743121487